# Where to hire poeple for data submission?

Tags: hiring

I have auto translated articles in portugues and I need to hire people to check the grammars etc.

Considering I need portugues (that can speak english a little to make agreements) where should I look for?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had success with [Odesk](http://odesk.com). Just be sure to spend the time filtering/interviewing candidates before hiring them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can find help in one of these sites:

- [Amazon's mtirk](https://www.mturk.com)
- [Fiverr](http://www.fiverr.com/)
- [Elance](http://www.elance.com/)